# safari browser angular $rootScope:infdig when url has space character

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, safari

I'm facing a wired issue in safari browser with AngularJS app.

**Here is my environment:**

- Windows 10 OS
- Safari browser 5.1.7
- AngularJs 1.4.8
- ui-router

**#Problem:**

Whenever a route url parameter has space character which encodes to %20 causes a $rootScope:infdig error.

```
Eg: http://localhost/club/The%20Club%20Arena
```

If I change the name of the club replace space character with underscore character, like follows it is working fine

```
Eg: http://localhost/club/The_Club_Arena
```

In Chrome/Firefox browsers urls with space character is working absolutely fine.

Comment: Changing the parameter values (i.e. replacing space with "-" or "_" works but I'm not supposed to do it in that way.